# How to rotate labels along with 3d cube created using openGl and android.

Tags: android, opengl-es

How to rotate labels along with 3 dimension  cube created using `openGl` and android.

I have created labels by hardcoding into the activity itself.

Comment: Are labels drawn with OpenGL?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to make images of the labels. Then load those images as textures, applied to sign objects added to the model. The sign objects could be simple rectangles made of two triangles from four points. If the same transformations applied to the cube are applied to the signs, the labels will move with the cube. Alternatively you could use the billboarding technique to keep the labels facing the camera.